# Merge rows of pandas data frame by grouping a column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

A beginner in panda and trying to achieve this in a pandas data frame-

Input- 
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/878jk.png)

I want an output like-

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LcNl.png)

It is groupby on name columns, the merge all the rows in Address and in same row
store the total count of address.

Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: groupby + agg , search the key words like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
(df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)
   .agg({'Count':'sum','Address':lambda x: ' \n '.join(x)}))
```

Output:

```
   Name                              Address  Count
0  Jake  XXXXXXXXX \n YYYYYYYYY \n ZZZZZZZZZ      3
1   Jon                  AAAAAAA \n BBBBBBBB      2
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. Any suggestions to practice, so I can be as good as you :)

Comment: @Ayum Check out the book listed in my profile by Ted Petrou and look at Stack Overflow.  If I helped you would you care to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) this answer.